# How to close down file handles after iNotify receives an event

Tags: python, linux, inotify

err:

> tail inotify resources exhausted

I am using Inotify for watching a directory for any file changes. But the problem is, the files are coming in fast which exhausts the Inotifier resources. It opens thousands of file handles. Is there a way by which when I get a notification, I could close the file handle right away? For example, if a file is created in the given directory I want the notifier to give me the path of that file and close the file handle, and wait for other changes?

```
import inotify.adapters
import os
from config import DOCKER_PATH_TO_STREAMS

notifier = inotify.adapters.Inotify()
for files in os.listdir(DOCKER_PATH_TO_STREAMS):
    notifier.add_watch(os.path.join(DOCKER_PATH_TO_STREAMS,files))

def watch_for_files():
    for event in notifier.event_gen():
        if event is not None:
            if 'IN_CREATE' in event[1]:
                val = os.path.join(event[2],event[3])
                if val.endswith(".jpeg") or val.endswith(".jpg"):
                    return val
```

Comment: What is "Inotifier"? Is that a third-party tool, library or some code you wrote?

Comment: Inotify *
Inotify (inode notify) is a Linux kernel subsystem that acts to extend filesystems to notice changes to the filesystem, and report those changes to applications.

Comment: You sound confused — inotify (Linux kernel subsystem) does not "open thousands of file handlers". Linux kernel does not open file handles on it's own — user-space code does. The question is: what code/tool are you using? inotifywatch? inotifywait?

Comment: @user1643723 I have edited the question. I think i am using inotifywatch

Comment: I am dumping ~100/second images into the directories which i am watching.

Comment: yes file handle. sorry

Comment: OK, which part of that code is opening file handles?

Comment: That is where i am confused myself. It open a file handle for each image(which is added to the watched dir)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... I've got somewhat confused from the comments on your question and the responses to them.

When the kernel opens a file, it checks the inotify queues to generate and queue a record for it.  The process that does that is the one that is issuing the `open(2)` system call, so it is strange for me that you can be glad opening more than 100 files/second, and the kernel losing information somewhere.  The problem you are having (most probably, but I can be wrong) is that the inotify processor doesn't have time to get such an amount of opening events and the queue gets full.

You have two approaches here.  The first involves extending the inotify queue to be able to support more resources.  I don't know if the inotify queue has some running time configuration that allows you to do this (anyway you can go to the kernel source and tweak on this)  The second probably involves *bad design* in the inotify processor... if your processor processes inotify records one at a time, and let's suppose you have to open a tcp connection to a remote site, to log such events, then you're in clear trouble.   As you don't show any code identifying the things that can be slowing the inotify reader I cannot give you some means to get to a solution, but the problem is there: the inotify receiver doesn't attend the queue to process 100 events/second (or more than you say in the comments)

Suppose you open a queue to receive requests.... but you then don't read it at a pace that allows it to empty.  Well, the queue has an upper limit, and once reached you cannot store more things in the queue.... you have to do something.  Do you see where do I want to go?